# Generating Random Numbers: updating seed

Tags: java

I'm trying to generate several random doublesbetween 0 and 1.  This is the code I ran but the numbers coming back are very close together.  I want numbers that are uniformally distributed over [0,1] or at least [0,1).  I

```
public class MyClass
long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
......
public double returnRandom() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    seed += 4; //update the seed
    rand.setSeed(seed); 
    return rand.nextDouble();
}
```

(loop over array to populate)  I end up with:

[0.10233441769044727]

[0.10484270731218648]

[0.1044843653222054]

[0.10412603823338551]

Comment: Why are you updating the seed instead of storing the instance of `Random`?

Comment: Your random values are close to each other, because all your instances of 'Random' are using seed-values that are almost equal to each other. Duffymo's solution should work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that you not update the seed.  You should also make Random a class instance and not instantiate one every time you call that method.

```
public class MyClass {
    private Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

public double returnRandom() {
    return this.random.nextDouble();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to update the seed of your `Random` object - in fact, it is probably a bad thing to do it.

```
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println(r.nextDouble());
    }
```

Output:

```
0.42997799629765443
0.025965300992295326
0.6819794805907442
0.5766417169200183
0.2709962942207633
0.5094285626768145
0.9364741774517189
0.7849361529399873
0.512486723637452
0.32604095225979
```

Answer (score 1):

try `Math.random()` it gives a uniform distribution in [0,1) - it creates a Random object behind the scenes and uses the same one for all subsequent calls. E.g

```
public double returnRandom() {
    return Math.random();
}
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using Math.random() versus Random class?

Comment: simpler code.  As I said, it creates an instance of Random anyway, but you don't have to deal with that.